# Signed eight-bit binary addition

Tags: java, binary

I'm trying to add two signed eight-bit numbers. All goes well until I try to add two negative numbers. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here's the part of my code where I add the numbers.

```
for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            bin4[i] = bin2[i] + bin3[i];
            if( i != 7 && bin4[i + 1] > 1)
            {
                carry[i + 1] = 1;
                bin4[i + 1] = 0;
                bin4[i] += 1;
            }
            if(i == 0)
            {
                if(bin4[i] > 1)
                {
                    bin4[i] = 0;
                    carry[i] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you add two negative numbers? Show us a test case, and describe the expected vs. actual behavior. See [mcve].

Comment: Your code does not handle carry correctly (unless there's some code you haven't shown) and you don't handle the situation of adding two 1-bits _and_ a carry bit.  You really need to step through the code one line at a time in your debugger, on a number of different test cases.

Comment: John Kugleman, when I add two negative numbers I get strange, incorrect answers. For example 11111110 + 11111011 or -2 + -5 gets me positive 5 instead of negative seven. -100 + -5 gets me positive 103.

Comment: As it turns out, it wasn't working for positive numbers either. I've changed the code and it seems to be working, except for with two negative numbers.